# Powershell Convert Date format in a CSV

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a CSV file with the following data

```
"Date","Time","Name","SourceIP","DestinationIP"
"Sep  1","03:55:57","mmt-5","172.16.48.158","22.22.22.22"
"Sep  1","03:55:57","mmt-5","172.16.48.158","22.22.22.22"
"Sep  1","03:55:57","mmt-5","172.16.48.158","22.22.22.22"
"Sep  1","03:55:57","mmt-5","172.16.48.158","22.22.22.22"
```

I would like to convert the date into something more usable like 09-01-2016 (the year would be the current year).
How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

That's easy using the `[DateTime]` class's `ParseExact` method. You supply the string that is a date, you tell it how the date is formatted, and you provide a culture or provider or something, but I always just use `$null`.

```
[datetime]::ParseExact("Sep  1","MMM  d",$null)
```

That comes out to:

```
Thursday, September 1, 2016 12:00:00 AM
```

So you could just do something like:

```
$Array | ForEach{[datetime]::ParseExact($_.Date,"MMM  d",$null)}
```

And that would convert each entry's Date property to a valid [datetime] object. Then you just format it however you want:

```
$Array | ForEach{[datetime]::ParseExact($_.Date,"MMM  d",$null).ToString("M-d-yyyy")}
```

That would output:

```
9-1-2016
```

Or for the exact thing you asked for use `"MM-dd-yyyy"` to get `09-01-2016`.

**Edit:** Thanks to wOxxOm for educating me about the third parameter's necessity when dealing with non-localized date formats! So, if this needs to be localized for other cultures, you will need to include that last parameter. That can be done as such:

```
$Culture = [cultureinfo]::GetCultureInfoByIetfLanguageTag('en-US')
$Array | ForEach{[datetime]::ParseExact($_.Date,"MMM  d",$Culture).ToString("MM-dd-yyyy")}
```

**Edit2:** Ok, to replace your current `Date` field with this information you could pass the array to the `Select` command, and create a new `Date` property on the fly, and discard the original, then pass that to `Export-CSV`:

```
$Array | Select *,@{l='Date';e={[datetime]::ParseExact($_.Date,"MMM  d",$null).ToString("M-d-yyyy")}} -Exclude Date | Export-CSV D-Sample-2.csv -NoType
```

Comment: It should be noted that an explicit culture info is required instead of `$null` on OS with a different system locale from the date being parsed e.g. `[cultureinfo]::GetCultureInfoByIetfLanguageTag('en-US')`

Comment: Thanks. I seem to be confused. It will output the date format that I want but will not modify my CSV file. Here is what I have tried `$Array = import-csv D-sample-1.csv
$Array | ForEach{[datetime]::ParseExact($_.Date,"MMM  d",$null).ToString("M-d-yyyy")}
$Array | export-csv D-sample-2.csv -notype`

Comment: @Eric The snippet you posted never modifies the $array you created. Do the import, modify the date, and send it straight to the export-csv

Comment: @StephenP I am a bit of a newbie at this. I tried this with no luck.
`import-csv D-sample-1.csv
$Array | ForEach{[datetime]::ParseExact($_.Date,"MMM  d",$null).ToString("M-d-yyyy")}
export-csv D-sample-2.csv -notype`